# Change name of listbox in MVC - getting default class name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Am having a listbox in MVC using HTML helpers

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(d => d.SelectedItems, new MultiSelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "listID", name = "listName"})
```

But the above code didnt change the name of listbox but id changed am getting name as **SelectedItems**.

is that the correct way ? what am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add attribute to you'r class where you have SelectedItems column

```
[DisplayName("listName")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this helper:

```
@Html.ListBox("listName", new MultiSelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "listID"})
```

Comment: How do i send selected values with this helper ?